# HibernateCriteria left join with OR where clause

Tags: mysql, hibernate, join

We have a problem with one of our queries where the query returns an inner join instead of a left join. The query is intended to retrieve all projects that a user has explicit access rights to (one of the usergroups the user is part of is defined as the project "User" Usergroup) OR implicit action (the project has no "User" Usergroup defined).

The relevant code:

```
    // HibernateCriteria is a custom class that has junction, conjunction, disjunction objects (the ones from Hibernate)
    ICriteria criteriaInProjectUserGroup = new HibernateCriteria();
    criteriaInProjectUserGroup.addEqualTo(Project.USERGROUP+"." +UserGroup.USERGROUPASSOCIATIONS+"."+UserGroupAssociation.USEROID, user.getOid());
    ICriteria criteriaNoProjectUserGroup = CriteriaFactory.createCriteria();
    criteriaNoProjectUserGroup.addIsNull(Project.USERGROUP); 
    /*The join (criteriaIn...) must be added to the simple is null criteria (criteriaNo...),
     * to result in a right outer join, otherwise an inner join is created by ojb which returns 
     * an empty result set */
    criteriaNoProjectUserGroup.addOrCriteria(criteriaInProjectUserGroup);
    IQuery query = QueryFactory.createQueryByCriteria(ProjectBean.class, criteriaNoProjectUserGroup);        
    Collection projects = broker.getCollectionByQuery(query);
```

addEqualTo is defined as:

```
public void addEqualTo(String attribute, Object value) {
    if (value!=null && value instanceof String && containsWildcards((String)value)) {
        addLike(attribute, value);
    }
    else {
        attribute = createAliasIfNecessary(attribute);
        conjunction.add(eq(attribute, value));
    }
}
```

addIsNull is defined as:

```
public void addIsNull(String attribute) {
    attribute = createAliasIfNecessary(attribute);
    conjunction.add(isNull(attribute));
}
```

addOrCriteria is defined as:

```
public void addOrCriteria(ICriteria criteria) {
    if(criteria instanceof HibernateCriteria) {
        HibernateCriteria subCriteria = (HibernateCriteria) criteria;
        Junction subJunction = subCriteria.resolveJunction();
        if(disjunction == null ) {
            disjunction = disjunction();
        }
        disjunction.add(subJunction);
        aliasNameSet.addAll(subCriteria.aliasNameSet);
    }
}
```

resolveJunction is defined as:

```
private Junction resolveJunction() {
    if(junction == null) {
        if(disjunction == null) { // no 'or' subcriteria have been added
            junction = conjunction; // then the main junction is simply the conjunction
        } else {
            // disjunction != null means an 'or' subcriteria has been already added.
            // then the main junction is disjunction with a conjunction as an operand
            junction = disjunction;
            junction.add(conjunction);
        }
    }
    return junction;
}
```

getCollectionByQuery extracts the critera into an org.hibernate.criterion.DetachedCriteria object:

```
    try {
        DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(clazz);
        // create aliases if necessary
        Set<String> createdAliasSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String aliasAssociationPath: aliasNameSet) {
            String[] nestedPropertiesArray = aliasAssociationPath.split("\\.");
            String previousNestedProperty = null;
            for(String nestedProperty: nestedPropertiesArray) {
                String currentAliasName = 
                    (previousNestedProperty == null ? nestedProperty : previousNestedProperty + "_" + nestedProperty);
                if(!createdAliasSet.contains(currentAliasName)) {
                    String currentAssociationPath = 
                        (previousNestedProperty == null ? nestedProperty : previousNestedProperty + "." + nestedProperty);
                    detachedCriteria.createAlias(currentAssociationPath, currentAliasName);
                    createdAliasSet.add(currentAliasName);
                }
                previousNestedProperty = currentAliasName;
            }
        }
        detachedCriteria.add(resolveJunction());
        return detachedCriteria;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        throw new PersistenceBrokerException(e);
    }
```

It then converts this to a org.hibernate.Criteria object and calls Criteria.list() on that function.

The resulting Mysql query is:

```
select
    this_.oid as oid1_41_2_,
    this_.archived as archived2_41_2_,
    this_.archivedDateTime as archived3_41_2_,
    this_.version as version4_41_2_,
    this_.adminGroupOid as adminGro5_41_2_,
    this_.buildScript as buildScr6_41_2_,
    this_.buildToolType as buildToo7_41_2_,
    this_.deployScript as deploySc8_41_2_,
    this_.deployToolType as deployTo9_41_2_,
    this_.description as descrip10_41_2_,
    this_.issueTrackingSystemOid as issueTr11_41_2_,
    this_.locked as locked12_41_2_,
    this_.name as name13_41_2_,
    this_.projectType as project14_41_2_,
    this_.testScript as testScr15_41_2_,
    this_.testToolType as testToo16_41_2_,
    this_.userGroupOid as userGro17_41_2_,
    this_.vcrOid as vcrOid18_41_2_,
    this_.vcrProjectName as vcrProj19_41_2_,
    usergroup1_.oid as oid1_65_0_,
    usergroup1_.archived as archived2_65_0_,
    usergroup1_.archivedDateTime as archived3_65_0_,
    usergroup1_.version as version4_65_0_,
    usergroup1_.description as descript5_65_0_,
    usergroup1_.name as name6_65_0_,
    usergroup1_.type as type7_65_0_,
    usergroup_2_.oid as oid1_58_1_,
    usergroup_2_.archived as archived2_58_1_,
    usergroup_2_.archivedDateTime as archived3_58_1_,
    usergroup_2_.version as version4_58_1_,
    usergroup_2_.scmUserOid as scmUserO6_58_1_,
    usergroup_2_.userGroupOid as userGrou5_58_1_ 
from
    .PROJECT this_ 
inner join
    .USERGROUP usergroup1_ 
        on this_.userGroupOid=usergroup1_.oid 
inner join
    .SCMUSER_USERGROUP usergroup_2_ 
        on usergroup1_.oid=usergroup_2_.userGroupOid 
where
    (
        (
            usergroup_2_.scmUserOid=3
        ) 
        or (
            this_.userGroupOid is null
        )
    )
```

The problem is that this only returns the projects that have a related UserGroup, because it's an inner join. This means that we don't get the projects without a usergroup defined.

I have found that the way to fix this is by using a left outer join for both of the joins, but I can't figure out how to make this work. The problem is that I can't touch the addX methods, because those are used absolutely everywhere in the service classes.

How do I adjust this code so the resultant SQL uses a left outer join instead of an inner join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found that the proper way to fix this is by adding a joinType to createAlias():

```
 detachedCriteria.createAlias(currentAssociationPath, currentAliasName, JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

However, this is a pretty involved fix because there is no current place where we use the joinType parameter, which means I need to further discuss this with more senior developers. For now, I will be using separate queries to retrieve the explicit and implicit access rights and joining them together in Java.